# Ошибка (pymysql.err.OperationalError) при подключении pymysql к mysql

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', unix_socket='/tmp/mysql.sock',
user='root', passwd=my_password, db='mysql')
```

**Выдаёт ошибку**

pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([Errno 2] No such file or directory)")

> мой pwd /home/pdk/Desktop
>   использую mysql server
>   linux 18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала проверьте, где лежит Ваш сокет. 
`mysqladmin variables | grep socket`
Проверьте подключение
`pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', db='mysql', user='root', passwd='pwd', unix_socket="/tmp/mysql.sock")`
Проверьте, на каком порту работает
`mysqladmin variables | grep port`
Если порт не 3306, то пропишите его в запросе
`pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', db='mysql', user='root', passwd='pwd', unix_socket="/tmp/mysql.sock", port=XXXX)`
Убедитесь, что у Вас `mysql`, а не `mysqld`